# Neo4j - List of arrays to a list of the elements in the arrays

Tags: arrays, neo4j, properties, cypher

I started to learn neo4j an therefor i've used the movie example db.
One of my Querys returned a list of arrays and i wondered how i could query the list of arrays as a list of the elements which are contained in the arrays.

My Cypher Request: (Every Film role of Tom Hanks in a movie)

```
    MATCH (:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"}) -[a:ACTED_IN]-> (:Movie) RETURN a.roles;
```

Result:

- ["Rep. Charlie Wilson"]
- ["Hero Boy", "Father", "Conductor", "Hobo", "Scrooge", "Santa Claus"]
- ["Jimmy Dugan"]
- ["Chuck Noland"]
- ["Jim Lovell"]
- ["Paul Edgecomb"]
- ["Dr. Robert Langdon"]
- ["Zachry", "Dr. Henry Goose", "Isaac Sachs", "Dermot Hoggins"]
- ["Mr. White"]
- ["Joe Banks"]
- ["Sam Baldwin"]
- ["Joe Fox"]

What i want:

- "Rep. Charlie Wilson"
- "Hero Boy"
- "Father"
- "Conductor"
- "Hobo"
- "Scrooge"
- "Santa Claus"
- "Jimmy Dugan"
- "Chuck Noland"
- "Jim Lovell"
- "Paul Edgecomb"
- "Dr. Robert Langdon"
- "Zachry"
- "Dr. Henry Goose"
- "Isaac Sachs"
- "Dermot Hoggins"
- "Mr. White"
- "Joe Banks"
- "Sam Baldwin"
- "Joe Fox"

Alternatively it would also be okay if the query returnd one large array like:

- ["Rep. Charlie Wilson", "Hero Boy", "Father", "Conductor", "Hobo", "Scrooge", "Santa Claus", "Jimmy Dugan", "Chuck Noland", "Jim Lovell", "Paul Edgecomb", "Dr. Robert Langdon", "Zachry", "Dr. Henry Goose", "Isaac Sachs", "Dermot Hoggins", "Mr. White", "Joe Banks", "Sam Baldwin", "Joe Fox"]

I've searched for a while now and i found no other solution than to write a custom java stored procedure and i realy hope there exists an simple build-in solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[a:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)
UNWIND a.roles AS role
RETURN role;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can set UNWIND on my lerning list... didnt know this keyword ^^